# Secure comment box in PHP

Tags: php, sql, security, insert, comments

I have had my comment box function on my website for a while and it was all grand until yesterday when I noticed a bizarre comment appear on my website that didn't look like anything normal. My question here is how do I prevent SQL injection attacks/ malicious spam etc.

I am not a big expert on PHP and i'm sure there is sth. missing in my code in terms of security.

I have introduced some basic validation functions to check if the values are not empty, do not contain abusive language, are of certain length etc.

what else could I improve in the below code to make it more secure for any attacks?

```
<?php

session_start();
require('execute.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
if(empty($_POST['name']))
{echo '<p style="color:red;"><b>Please provide a valid name</b></p>';}
else 
{
    $fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['name']));
}

if(empty($_POST['comment']))
{echo '<p style="color:red;"><b>Please provide a valid comment</b></p>';}
else 
{
    $cm = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comment']));
}

$minimum_n = '/[a-zA-Z]{3,}/';
if(!preg_match($minimum_n, $_POST['name']))
{$_POST['name'] = NULL; echo '<p style="color:red;"><b>Your name is too short or has incorrect format</b></p>';}

$minimum_c = '/[a-zA-Z]{5,}/';
if(!preg_match($minimum_c, $_POST['comment']))
{$_POST['comment'] = NULL; echo '<p style="color:red;"><b>Your message is too short or in incorrect format</b></p>';}

    $pattern = '/(shit|crap|http|href)(s|ed|ing|ty|off)?/i'; /* Removed offensive words */
if(preg_match($pattern, $_POST['name']))
{$_POST['name'] = NULL; echo '<p style="color:red;"><b>You have chosen inappropriate nickname. Please use a different one</b></p>';}

if(preg_match($pattern, $_POST['comment']))
{$_POST['comment'] = NULL; echo '<p style="color:red;"><b>You have used inappropriate word(s) in your message</b></p>';}    

if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['comment']))
{
    require('execute.php');
    $q = "INSERT INTO comment (name, comment, date)
    VALUES ('$fn', '$cm' ,NOW())";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    mysqli_close($dbc);
}
}

?>

</div>

<div class="container_16 grid_8 alpha lefter">

<?php
session_start();
require('execute.php');
$q = "SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY user_id DESC";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{

     echo "<p>" . ''. "<b>" . ' ' . $row['id']. ' ' . $row['name'] . ' ' . "</b>". ' ' . $row['comment']. ' ' . $row['date'] . ' ' . "</br>";

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caution Security: the default character set
>
> The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the
>   API function mysqli_set_charset() for it to affect
>   mysqli_real_escape_string(). See the concepts section on character
>   sets for more information.

That's what php manual said about mysqli_real_escape_string function. So try to set proper charset with mysqli_set_charset() function.

Comment: I have this in my execute.php file;

    <?php

    $dbc = mysqli_connect('XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX')
    OR die(mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf-8');

The manual mentions that the mysqli_set_charset requires just the utf-8 parameter; how does that make the difference?

Comment: There is procedural style with two attributes and oo style with just one so You can use $dbc->mysqli_set_charset('utf-8'); or mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf-8');

Comment: mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf-8'); is what I had in my code from the start; yet it didn't seem secure enough. Any other suggestions?